# Delete Hotkey that was created during the Ubuntu 21.10 update

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I upgraded from version 20.04 to 21.10 ,at this time in the terminal
A window has opened:
'configuring keyboard-configuration'
Then it asked me to select the hotkey to switch between the two languages ​​and I chose ctrl + shift **but now some hotkeys that contain ctrl + shift do not work...**
so I decided to delete this hotkey but in setting->keyboard->keyboard shortcuts->typing , there is just Super+space and there is no ctrl + shift to delete...

**how can I delete this hotkey?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in two places.

First open `/etc/default/keyboard` for editing and drop that option from `XKBOPTIONS`.

Second install `gnome-tweaks` (if it's not already installed), open Tweaks, navigate to *Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Switching to another layout*, and uncheck it there.

Comment: thanks you solved that problem!